# React Js - Llenar arreglo de forma dinámica

Tags: array, reactjs

Estoy creando una app en la que necesito llenar una array de forma dinámica con elementos seleccionados mediante un checkBox, sin embrago al realizarlo agrega el primer elemento y al seleccionar otro lo único que sucede es que se reemplaza y sigue habiendo solo un item.

```
const Product = ({doc, type, type_card}) => { 
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('List', list)
    }, [list])

    return (
        <Container type={type}>
            <div>
                <p>{doc.product_code}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                {type_card ? 
                    <button>Editar</button>
                :
                    <button>Ver Producto</button>
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                {type_card ? 
                    <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(doc.id, doc.ref)} >Eliminar</button>
                :
                    <div>
                        // Añadir elementos al arreglo
                        Add
                        <input 
                            type="checkbox"
                            id={`${doc.id}`} 
                            onChange={e => {
                                if (e.target.checked) {
                                    setList([...list, {
                                        product_code: doc.product_code,
                                        id: doc.id
                                    }])
                                } 
                            }} />
                        
                        <label htmlFor={`${doc.id}`}>
                            <div></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo efectuar dicha acción de forma correcta. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si es lo que estás buscando, pero intentaré darte una solución.

Le hice varias modificaciones a tu código para que no dependa de `props` que le lleguen desde algún componente padre, para así poder hacerte una demostración mediante *CodeSandbox*.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Product = ({ type_card }) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [doc, setDoc] = useState({
    id: "dsfds",
    ref: "dsfs",
    product_code: "sdfsd"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("List", list);
  }, [list]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>{doc.product_code}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        {type_card ? <button>Editar</button> : <button>Ver Producto</button>}
      </div>
      <div>
        {type_card ? (
          <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(doc.id, doc.ref)}>
            Eliminar
          </button>
        ) : (
          <div>
            Añadir elementos al arreglo
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={`${doc.id}`}
              onChange={(e) => {
                if (e.target.checked) {
                  let newList = list;
                  newList.push({
                    product_code: doc.product_code,
                    id: doc.id
                  });
                  console.log(newList);
                  setList(newList);
                }
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`${doc.id}`}>
              <div></div>
            </label>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

[image: Edit new]

Básicamente, lo más importante de este código es la manera en la que ingreso los datos al array `list`.

```
onChange={(e) => {
                if (e.target.checked) {
                  let newList = list;
                  newList.push({
                    product_code: doc.product_code,
                    id: doc.id
                  });
                  console.log(newList);
                  setList(newList);
                }
              }}
```

Fijate que en el evento `onChange` del checkbox, por cada vez que le hago click se agrega el JSON al estado `list`, como se puede observar en los `console.log()`.

Para lograrlo, primero creo un nuevo objeto llamado `newList` en donde guardo el valor actual del estado `list`. Luego le hago un `.push` ingresandole el objeto que deseo sumar a mis datos anteriores. Y finalmente los guardo actualizando el estado con el `setList()`.

De esta manera puedo acumular en mi array todos los datos que deseo guardar.

Obviamente, esto es solo una demostración en la que por supuesto no nos va a servir de mucho guardar siempre el mismo dato. Pero en casos practicos podrías renderizar una serie de objetos guardados en un array mediante un `.map` y habilitar cada checkbox para que al tocarlos se vayan guardando los datos seleccionados.

Espero haberte ayudado o al menos acercarte a la solución que estabas buscando.